# How to stop SetInterval in JS

Tags: javascript

Pls help i want to stop and reset

```
function likeButtonFunction () {
    if (unlikeText.classList.contains('not-active')) {
        likeText.classList.add('not-active');
        unlikeText.classList.remove('not-active');
        let myInterval = setInterval(hearts, 100);
        return myInterval;
    }
    else if (likeText.classList.contains('not-active')) {
        unlikeText.classList.add('not-active');
        likeText.classList.remove('not-active');
        myInterval = clearInterval(myInterval, 0);
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
}

likeButton.addEventListener('click', likeButtonFunction);
```

I tried clearInterval() but it didnt work

Comment: `myInterval` is not defined in the `else if` block. You have to declare `myInterval` outside of this function

Comment: @Konrad So how to start interval by click on button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let myInterval;
function likeButtonFunction () {
    if (unlikeText.classList.contains('not-active')) {
        likeText.classList.add('not-active');
        unlikeText.classList.remove('not-active');
        myInterval = setInterval(hearts, 100);
    }
    else if (likeText.classList.contains('not-active')) {
        unlikeText.classList.add('not-active');
        likeText.classList.remove('not-active');
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
}

likeButton.addEventListener('click', likeButtonFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `myInterval` does not exist in the else block.

What you have to do is to define it in global scope.

```js
let myInterval = undefined;
function likeButtonFunction () {
    if (!myInterval && unlikeText.classList.contains('not-active')) {
        likeText.classList.add('not-active');
        unlikeText.classList.remove('not-active');
        myInterval = setInterval(hearts, 100);
        return myInterval;
    }
    else if (myInterval && likeText.classList.contains('not-active')) {
        unlikeText.classList.add('not-active');
        likeText.classList.remove('not-active');
        if (myInterval) {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            myInterval = undefined;
        }
    }
}

likeButton.addEventListener('click', likeButtonFunction);
```

With the modified code above, you will have a global variable called `myInterval`, what can be used to track the interval object.
It's type is `number | undefined` in TS.

The DOM modifications + interval starting happens if bot the conditions present (the interval is not defined and the class is not added to the element). Same applies for the else statement (if the interval is present and the class is present as well).

Please not that `setInterval()` returns numbers starting from `1` so the falsyness check works, but if you'd like to prettify your code you can add `myInterval === undefined` to the check block.